# What is the proper way to have user profiles like facebook.com/USERNAMEHERE? I'm currently using domain.com/users.html?USERNAMEHERE

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, url

I'm looking to have URLs for each username. However, the only way I've figured out how to do this is by using search queries (? question marks). For example, in Node.js I am getting the 'location.search' tag, which returns whatever is after the '?' in www.domain.com/users.html?USERNAME. However, I would like to have it where I can use www.domain.com/users/USERNAME.

I am using Firebase and Node.js

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are generating the content.

A couple of methods that come to mind:

- getting the username from the URL in a node.js
- using rewrites in firebase hosting

### Method 1:

If you are using some kind of server-side rendering, you can just get the username from the URL and dynamically serve the content. Express example:

```
app.get('/user/:username', function(req , res){
  res.send("This is the profile for: " + req.params.username);
});
```

---

### Method 2:

If you serve the same HTML file for every user and populate it with user data on the client, you can use rewrites in your firebase hosting config:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/user/*",
        "destination": "/user/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This rewrites `domain.com/user/username/` to `domain.com/user/index.html`.

Note: It does not rewrite `domain.com/user/username/otherpage/`. To do that you will need to add the rewrite:

```
{
  "source": "/user/*/otherpage/",
  "destination": "/path/to/otherpage/"
}
```

Note: If you use this method look out for 404 errors if you reference resources using relative paths. For example imagine this was a HTML file in /user/:

```
<!-- inside of /user/index.html -->
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

This path will be `/users/username/javascript.js` and may return index.html, which is a problem. To fix this, use an absolute path:

```
<!-- inside of /user/index.html -->
<script src="/user/javascript.js"></script>
```